# istream_iterator ignoring EOF (Ctrl+D) when reading chars

Tags: c++, eof, cin, istream, istream-iterator

I'm trying to use `istream_iterator` for reading characters from `cin`. I've read that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> sends an `EOF` character which ends the input stream. Unfortunately, something is going wrong with it. Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  istream_iterator<char> it(cin), eos;
  while (it != eos) clog << *(it++);
}
```

I'm running it and typing: `as df`, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
It outputs only `asd` without the last `f` and then hangs waiting for input. When I type `gh` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> again, it prints the remaining `f` at last, and the `g` from next input, but again without the last `h`. And when I finally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> without typing anything, it prints the remaining `h` and exits.

I expected it to read `asdf` and exit, since I already pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the end of this first sequence.

Why is it still waiting for input after getting `EOF`?
Why it doesn't print the last character read before `EOF`?
And why it exits only when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> without typing anything before?
How does this loop need to change to make it behave in the way I expect? (i.e. stop reading immediately after getting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> sequence in the input, no matter I typed anything before or not, and reading *all* characters up to the `EOF`).

Comment: If you're using Windows/DOS EOF is `CTRL+Z`, not `CTRL+D`.

Comment: I know. But thanks for completing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Input iterators require special care. Rewrite your loop this way and the behavior will become similar to any other character input loop:

```
while (it != eos)
{
    clog << *it;
    it++;
}
```

That will take care of "Why it doesn't print the last character"

PS: as for EOF in the middle of the line, it is the [POSIX-mandated behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09):

> When received, all the bytes waiting to be read are immediately passed to the process without waiting for a newline, and the EOF is discarded. Thus, if there are no bytes waiting (that is, the EOF occurred at the beginning of a line), a byte count of zero shall be returned from the read(), representing an end-of-file indication.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Now it works as I expected :) (taking into account what Keith Thompson wrote below and you too in your updated answer). But could you explain what's that "special care" and why it is needed? (ie. why your code works and mine doesn't). I'd like to understand it better, not only copy-paste.

Comment: The `*(it++)` forces the input iterator to make a read from the input stream before it outputs what was already previously read.  So your last character has already been read after receiving the first CTRL+D, but it can't be output until you input another character (in this case another CTRL+D to indicate EOF).  Sequencing `*it` and `it++` now outputs the previously read character before trying to read another character.  Thus your last character is printed and then the input waits for the last CTRL+D to indicate EOF in the middle of a line.

Comment: @SasQ I got beat by 14 seconds, but to add a couple details, input iterators read when incremented, that is `read()` is a side-effect of evaluation of `it++`, and before the function call to `operator<<()`, side-effects on its arguments (`clog` and `*it++`) must be complete. That's how it forces the read to occur before the output even if the intent (judging by post-increment) was the opposite.

Comment: @Cubbi: Don't worry ;) Your effort has been awarded too.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix-like systems, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> triggers an end-of-file condition only at the beginning of a line (i.e., immediately after typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  To trigger an end-of-file condition in the middle of a line, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice.

Comment: Ah, so that answers one of my questions: why `Ctrl+D` doesn't end the stream if I typed something before it. This clears me a lot. But I still wonder why pushing `Ctrl+D` after typing something *does* send these characters to my program and they appear. It's like `Ctrl+D` is kind of working (it stops reading input for a while), but not with the full power of `EOF` (closing the stream completely).<br/>BTW how do you make those nice button-like frames around your text? :>

Comment: OK nevermind, I figured it out with these button-like borders ;)

Comment: @SasQ: It looks like <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> interrupts line buffering, so the program can immediately see what was typed even though it isn't at the end of a line.  I'm not 100% sure of this; I'm sure it's documented somewhere.  Oh, and it's "<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>".